# automatically disable "build automatically" in eclipse during ant run

Tags: eclipse, plugins, ant, automation, build-process

Is there a way to automatically disable the "build automatically" setting in eclipse while an ant build is running?

1. It should listen for an ant task being started
2. check if the setting is enabled
3. disable it temporarily
4. listen for the ant build to finish
5. restore the previous setting

I would like to have this, because having this enabled makes my ant build take ~10 minutes and having this setting disabled lets it finish in ~5 minutes. I often forget to always change the setting and so I waste lots of time waiting. Having this automated would improve my build-cycles.

If there is nothing out there yet, I would be willing to write a plugin for this. In that case does anyone have pointers about how to listen for the events and change the setting? :)

## EDIT:

I want to fix this for manually started ant builds via right clicking the build.xml and clicking run as -> ant build. I do not use ant builders in my eclipse project configuration.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that you narrow down what resources you actually want to refresh in the Ant Builder's `Refresh` tab

[image]

and/or move Ant Builder behind Java builder in the `Builders` configuration.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this does not happen because of an ant builder, but during manually started and builds. Like right click the build.xml and selecting "run as -> ant build". So there is no such property. :)